# Replace column values from dict adding rows when needed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I optimize the following in pandas?

It's looping through the new_values one item at a time. I would like to speed it up using bulk operations.

I would like to replace all existing values in a DataFrame column with values from a dict. New rows should be added if necessary. Missing data should be left as an empty string.

Here is code that does it. I simplified it considerably. In reality there are multiple rows and columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, orient='index', columns=['Alias'])
print(df)
new_values = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
df['Alias'] = ''
for k, v in new_values.items():
    df.loc[k, 'Alias'] = v
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Alias
a      1
b      2
  Alias
a      
b     3
c     4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to solve this easily.

First convert `new_values` to a dataframe like this:

```
In [2700]: s = pd.Series(new_values).to_frame()
```

Now use `df.join`:

```
In [2709]: x = df.join(s, how='outer')[0].fillna('').to_frame('Alias')

In [2710]: x
Out[2710]: 
  Alias
a      
b     3
c     4
```

Comment: @ChaimG Please let me know if the answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new dataframe after updating the input dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index', columns=['Alias'])
print(df)

>>>     Alias
       a      1
       b      2


new_values = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}

to_delete = {k:'' for k in dict1.keys() if k not in new_values.keys()}

dict1.update(new_values)
dict1.update(to_delete)

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index', columns=['Alias'])
print(df2)

>>>     Alias
       a      
       b     3
       c     4
```

Comment: My DataFrame actually contains multiple columns, but only some are being changed. I had oversimplified the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_values, orient='index',columns=['Alias'])#New dataFrame from dict
df=df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]#From your desired answer, you seem to want anything in df and not in df1 included but with null values. I am therefore applying a filter
df1=df1.append(df.assign(Alias=''))#Null Alias and append
print(df1)



    Alias
b     3
c     4
a
```